# Функционал QRadioButton в окне QMessageBox

Tags: python, pyqt5, qradiobutton, qmessagebox

*Вопрос*: Возможно ли в тело `QMessageBox` встроить функционал `QradioButton`? Скрипт (**radio.py**).

*Трудности*: не получается в тело стандартного окна `QMessageBox` (с иконкой `setIcon()` и кнопками) встроить `QRadioButton`.

*Для примера*: скрин с окном  `QMessageBox` и встроенным в него `QCheckBox`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**radio.py**

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton,
                             QButtonGroup, QRadioButton, QLabel, QApplication, QMessageBox,
                             QHBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Widg(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widg, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Внимание!')

        label_tk = QLabel()
        label_tk.setText('''
          <p> 
            <img src="smiley.gif" alt="icon face" 
             width="42" height="42" 
             style="vertical-align:top"> 
            Необходимо выбрать браузер.
          </p>
         ''')
        # !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.label_p = QLabel()
        self.check_button = None  # !!! +++

        self.group = QButtonGroup()
        self.rad1 = QRadioButton("Coogle Chrome (рекомендуется)")
        self.rad2 = QRadioButton("PhantomJS Driver")

        self.btn1 = QPushButton('Старт')
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.btn1_clicked)  # !!! +++

        self.btn2 = QPushButton('Отмена')
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.btn2_clicked)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label_tk, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.rad1)
        layout.addWidget(self.rad2)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_p)

        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH.addWidget(self.btn1)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.btn2)
        layout.addLayout(layoutH)

        self.group.addButton(self.rad1)
        self.group.addButton(self.rad2)
        self.group.buttonClicked.connect(self.group_check_button)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    # !!! +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def group_check_button(self, rb):
        self.check_button = rb

    def btn1_clicked(self):
        if not self.check_button:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                'Вы не сделали выбор?')
            return
        print(f'Выбран: {self.check_button.text()}')
        self.label_p.setText(f'Выбран: {self.check_button.text()}')
        time.sleep(1.0)
        if self.check_button.text() == "Coogle Chrome (рекомендуется)":
            print('Coogle Chrome (рекомендуется)')
            # import image_chrome
        else:
            print('PhantomJS Driver')
            # import image
        self.close()
    # !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def btn2_clicked(self):
        print('Нажата кнопка: отмена')
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widg()
    w.resize(250, 250)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Что вам мешает создать своё диалоговое сообщение?

Comment: Наследуйте QDialog и вперёд.

Comment: Вопрос состоит не в том, что бы хоть как то работало, а можно ли это реализовать в MessageBox?

Comment: Tusher, объясните пожалуйста лучше, что именно вас не устраивает в опубликованном вами коде? Что вы имели ввиду когда написали: "Вопрос состоит не в том, чтобы хоть как то работало,...". Почему вы считаете, что реализации в `MessageBox` - это правильная идея?

Comment: Вечер добрый. Причин несколько: 1.  `QMessageBox` задумывался как диалоговое окно для информирования пользователя или для того, чтобы задать пользователю вопрос и получить ответ; 2. `QCheckBox` в окнах `QMessageBox` работает; 3. то что я не знаю как это сделать, не значит что так сделать нельзя, вот и спрашиваю, а возможно?